# Why viruses such as covid-19 are shaped like a sphere from a mathematical point of view

Tags: geometry, biology

I can't find anything online about the relationship between spheres and the envelope of a virus from a purely mathematical point of view, what I need to know is why the outer-layer of viruses is a sphere, asked my professor about it but even he couldn't answer me.

Comment: Maybe an interesting question... but absolutely not a math one.

Comment: It likely has something to do with trying to minimize the energy required to construct said envelope: The unit sphere requires the least surface area to contain its volume.

Comment: Many viruses aren't.https://courses.lumenlearning.com/boundless-microbiology/chapter/structure-of-viruses/

Comment: [Biology.SE](https://biology.stackexchange.com) might be a better place for this question. The question ["Does a virus have a well defined shape?"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/91031) was closed for lack-of-focus (although not before receiving an answer), but perhaps yours would fare better.

Comment: Maybe the answer is the same reason that the earth is round or bubbles are round, their semipermeable layer is similar to the one of a cell, where the sphere is the shape that has equal pressure in all directions whereas another shape, like a cube, has more pressure at the centers of the faces.

Comment: [Related.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3603852/104041)